# nivo slider image dispaly in template but do not display in CodeIgniter what is the reason?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

**1.Image of nivo slider display in my template . But when I use it into codeIgniter then it can not display.
2.Others content of template shows but only image does not show .
3.With firebug I saw when nivoslider div act then it show image tag where visibility:hidden and background show url of image not found.**

```
I am newbie . Please help me.


Master page :
```

This is code:

```
 <title>This is Title</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <!-- Bootstrap -->
                <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
                <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

                <!-- Amazing Mobile Menu CSS -->
                <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/jquery.fs.naver.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />        

                <!-- News Tickr CSS -->
                <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/ticker-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

                <!-- Bebas Webfont -->
                <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>fonts/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">  
                <!-- Nivo Slider CSS -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
                <!-- Main CSS -->
                <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

                <!-- Responsive Framework -->
                <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">



        **html code for nivoslider:**

        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/toystory.jpg" alt="" />
                                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/up.jpg" alt="" />
                                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/walle.jpg" alt="" />
                                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/nemo.jpg" title="#htmlcaption" alt="" />
                                </div>

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''    **others code here**![enter image description here][1]

    this code for script:

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#slider').nivoSlider({
                controlNav: false
            });
        });
        </script>   
            <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.ticker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#js-news').ticker();
                });
            </script>       
            <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.fs.naver.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("nav").naver({
                    animated: true
                });     
            </script>
            <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsaIJ.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`<?php echo base_url();?>img/toystory.jpg`

into

`<?php echo base_url();?>/img/toystory.jpg`

(note the slash).

Or even better: remove all `<?php echo base_url();?>` and add in your head:

`<base href="/" />` or `<base href="<?php echo base_url();?>/" />`

Comment: Thanks Luc Handriks .  It works.  Once again thank you for help me..........................................